# Link Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) work item discussion area with slack for 2-way interaction

Tags: visual-studio, slack

NOTE: Still new to Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) and Slack.

Anyone know of a (cheap) way to integrate Slack and the "Discussion" area of a work item in a two way fashion?

The idea would be that each work item would have its own channel (or tag or room or whatever slack can do) so that anything added through VSTS work item discussion would then show up in that specific slack area thing. Then also anything added in Slack would then be added into the VSTS discussion area?

It would one to be mobile and still give feedback/discussion on specific work items. I think it works that way with team rooms through the standard slack integration, but if not, would want that working 2-way also.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Comment: We just had a discussion about this very thing. Would be quite helpful.